# when i am trying to save the data to mysql, an exception is being thrown( java.sql.SQLException)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, awt

```
import java.awt.Panel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class one implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ghar hisab");
    JButton b = new JButton("save");
    Panel p = new Panel();
    JTextField f = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField f1 = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Enter the first name");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Enter the last name");
    String s1,s2;
    String ppl;
    int people;

            void display() throws Exception{
                                p.add(l);
                                p.add(f);
                                p.add(l1);
                                p.add(f1);
                                p.add(b);

                                frame.setSize(400,400);

                                frame.setVisible(true);
                                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                frame.getContentPane().add(p);
                                s1=f.getText();
                                s2=f1.getText();


                //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                //Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people","root","desire");

                //Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            //  String s3= "insert into name values s1 + s2";
            //  stat.executeUpdate(s3);



        //  stat.executeQuery("insert into name (first,last) values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");
            b.addActionListener(this);

        //  ResultSet rs= stat.executeQuery("insert into name (first,last) values("arun","yadav"));


            //while(rs.next()){
        //      System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
        //  }




        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people","root","desire");

            Statement stat = con.createStatement();

            stat.executeQuery("insert into name (first,last) values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("the exception caught is "+e);
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: getting the stack trace from the exception will help you debug this.

Comment: Insufficient information - please post the stack trace.  Don't print that message - it's less information than is available to you.

Comment: replacing stat.executeQuery with stat.executeUpdate solves the exception problem. New entry in database table is also made , but in the field of "first" and "last" nothing is being shown .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the stack trace, it's difficult to tell.  Either you aren't establishing a connection or the values in your SQL are causing the query to error out (perhaps one or both are null).  I'd suggest putting a break point on con, and see if the object is null.  And also see what s1 and s2 are.  Below, I've added two lines.  You need to close your statement and connection.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people","root","desire");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        stat.executeQuery("insert into name (first,last) values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");
        stat.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("e.fillInStackTrace:" + e.fillInStackTrace());
        System.out.println("e.getCause:" + e.getCause());
        System.out.println("e.getLocalizedMessage:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("e.getMessage.:" + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("e.getStackTrace:" + e.getStackTrace());
        System.out.println("e.initCause:" + e.initCause());
        System.out.println("e.printStackTrace:" + e.printStackTrace());
        System.out.println("e.toString:" + e.toString());       
    }
}
```

Comment: replacing stat.executeQuery with stat.executeUpdate solves the exception problem. New entry in database table is also made , but in the field of "first" and "last" nothing is being shown .

Comment: When you say "first" and "last" field, are you querying the database after the insert is done?  Like the following: SELECT * FROM [name] ???

Comment: does the user (root) have proper permissions to perform INSERT commands?  I imagine so, since it's root, but just wanted to make sure.  Are the SQL data types for those fields consistent with the data you're sending from the Java code?

Comment: try that new code in the catch.. that should get you the details you need.

Comment: although take the ones out that do not have a return type of "string" .. otherwise you'll get another exception.  
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you import PreparedStatement, but your code never uses it. Well, I don't know much about SQL but I do that when you use a PreparedStatement you are less likely to have problems. Here is a simple example for an insert:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Name (First, Last) VALUES (?, ?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, s1 );
stmt.setString( 2, s2 );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I took the liberty of uppercasing the table name and columns names since that is the way most people would create the table names.

Edit:

```
s1=f.getText();
s2=f1.getText();
```

When that code is executed the text field contains no values since the user hasn't had a chance to enter any data into the text fields yet. Those two statements need to be moved to the actionPerformed() method.

Comment: replacing stat.executeQuery with stat.executeUpdate solves the exception problem. New entry in database table is also made , but in the field of "first" and "last" nothing is being shown .

Comment: @Apurva, make sure the variables s1 and s2 actually contain values. See my edit.